# How to remove the resize corner from a textarea element?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a simple text editor - the text input is a textarea element. I want to remove the two lines used to change the box size (in fact, if possible, I'd like to fix the box size so it can't be changed).

This is what I'm talking about:
[image]

EDIT: Here's the code:

```
// HTML
<textarea id="canvas" placeholder="Write something..."></textarea>

// CSS
#canvas {
  border: 1px dashed #999;
  background: transparent;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: Edited from 'canvas' to 'textarea' : )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try CSS properties **[`resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize)** and **[`appearance`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance)**:

```css
#textbox {
    border: 1px dashed #999;
    background: transparent;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;

    resize:none;

    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
    appearance: textfield;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textbox" placeholder="Write something..."></textarea>
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Add the property `resize:none` to the textarea. 
Here is the working code:

```css
#canvas {
    border: 1px dashed #999;
    background: transparent;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    resize:none;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="canvas" placeholder="Write something..."></textarea>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @tkim90 do tell me if anymore changes are needed

Comment: This is perfect, thank you!!